# Can't display Unicode characters in web browser?

Tags: ubuntu, unicode, utf-8

I typed unicode characters in a file named 'test.html' and then saved it. The thing is gedit can display properly , but when I open the html in webbrowsers the characters become like this "† ® ¾ ° ¨ ¾ ® ª ¿ ß ¾ ² " and " à¦®à§‡à¦¯à¦¼à¦° à¦¹à¦²à§" , A bunch of 3/4 , R and gibberish icons.Both chrome and firefox is having trouble , Only gedit is able to display the characters properly . How can I fix this ?

For clarification , here is the original text in gedit:

[image: Original text]

And here is how is it viewed in browser:

[image: As displayed in browser]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can't show chinese character for html on linux server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713564/cant-show-chinese-character-for-html-on-linux-server)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Answer (score 1):

Declare the encoding of your HTML file. Make sure to save it in UTF-8.  Here's a minimal example:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<h1>उद् उ ज्योतिः अमृतम् विश्वजन्यम्</h1>
```

Comment: Also make sure the webserver is reporting UTF-8 as the charset in the `Content-Type` response header.